# Does firebase storage charges only for storage or for showing image as well?

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage

Could someone please clarify. If I use only Firebase Storage and save images there and show that images in my app by providing the URL of the image.  Will I be charged only for amount of memory I use OR I will have to pay for users that look at those images in their app as well? If so that means as more traffic I have in my app with that images more money I will have to pay?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Firebase pricing can be found here:

https://firebase.google.com/pricing

The delivery of content from Firebase Storage is indeed a chargeable concept.  I believe that as of 2021-10, the first GB/day is free with $0.12/GB after that.  You are also charged for actual requests ... the first 50K/day are free with a charge of $0.004/10K after that.

Comment: Thank you. I saw that link. But it is not covered for 100%. So just to clarify - 1) the first GB/day is free with $0.12/GB after that - means if I DOWNLOAD from the storage? 2) charged for actual requests - means if I show one image that stores in the storage to two unique users it will be counted as 2 requests?

Comment: Howdy Boris ... Google does not appear to charge for bringing data TO Cloud Storage ... so there is no charge for UPLOADING to storage, only for retrieving (DOWNLOAD) from Storage.  For the requests, every individual request received at Cloud Storage to download (retrieve) an image is its own event.   Ask yourself the question ... does the request result in data coming out of Google and over the internet which costs Google money.

Comment: I'm sorry but still what is the definition of the DOWNLOAD? for me download load is when you saving that file from Google storage to local storage. But for me if I just show the image on the website the link in the image view is not downloading since you actually dont move file outside the storage. You just use the link. So please clarify on this moment? Do I need to pay if I use that link on my website?

Comment: Howdy Boris ... ahh ... with you now.  In this context, when a browser or app requests an image to view and the image is stored on Google storage, we say that the image is "downloaded" from Google storage.  If it helps, we could use the word "transferred" as a synonym for "downloaded".  Putting it another way ... ANYTIME data moves FROM Google storage out over the internet ... you will be charged.  The current rate is $0.12/GB.

Comment: Thank you for your clarification. Since they charge for that there is no point to store images there because if your traffic increase you will pay more :(

Comment: But is there a way to count that "DOWNLOADS" programmatically from the code? So I could track it and control this process?

Comment: The Firebase product is built on top of Google Cloud Platform.  What this means is that there are tons of metrics available immediately ready for your perusal.  This includes billing budgets and much, much more.